# Test for write permission fails even though permissions are 777

Tags: docker, unix, solr, permissions

I am currently trying to get apache solr running in my docker environment. The entrypoint script of solr checks if the directory /var/solr has write permissions before continuing with the execution.
This check fails and therefore the container wont start.

I digged into the startup scripts and found this line:

```
if [ ! -w "$dir" ]; then
    echo "Cannot write to $dir as $(id -u):$(id -g)"
    ls -ld "$dir"
    exit 1
fi
```

This check fails cause for some reason it states that there are no write permissions for the user solr:solr.

When I run the container in interactive mode, bypassing the entrypoint scripts by using:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash solr
```

I can check for permissions on the /var/solr directory and they state that all permissions are given:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 solr solr  4.0K Jul 31 09:22 solr
```

I am also able to write to the directory.

But when running

```
test -w /var/solr; echo $?
```

I get "1" back, meaning writing permissions are not given.

I am out of ideas what the reasoning for this could be, so maybe one of you have an idea?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do you have SELinux running ? Look for AVC denials in your audit logs.